# Convert SMTP Client Mail message to HTML

Tags: c#

I have an issue with an mvc4 application in witch i would like to send a generated html page created with HTML + C#. The problem is that when i recieved the email i see my c# code like the exemple bellow:
[Recieved Email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy5Pa.png)

But in the mail preview i can see the correct values like this:
[Mail Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJX4K.png)

So this is my EmailTemplate method:

```
<pre>
 public static async Task<string> EMailTemplate (string template)
        {
            var templateFilePath =HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Views/Home/") + template + ".cshtml";
            StreamReader objstreamreaderfile = new StreamReader(templateFilePath);
            var body = await objstreamreaderfile.ReadToEndAsync();
            objstreamreaderfile.Close();
            return body;

        }
</pre>
```

Please if you have any idea how to convert my template to Html without inclouding my C# code.

Thanks,

Comment: where do you see the mail preview? By running the view in Visual Studio or any other editor?

Comment: You may be interested in https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcMailer/

Answer (score 2):

Use **Pure Html template** (Not a cshtml view) with Inline CSS and Absolute image URIs for email body and fill it text templates. See the below image.

[image: Demo Email Template]

In the above image, field with ##...## are text templates.

Now read this HTML template as a string and replace ##...## fields by some dynamic information using the C# code (Actually any language code). You can use `string.Replace()` method to replace these fields by actual values. I have already used this method and it is working fine. I hope this will help you too.